# Suppress false positive warning for retriggering a Windows timer

Tags: code-analysis, cppcheck, ttimer

I wish to retrigger a Windows timer using a VCL6 `TTimer` object. I'm doing this by toggling the `Enabled` property, this of course can be confusing, but I added a comment about this. For Cppcheck I added a comment as well in its language:

```
m_pTimer->Enabled = false;
// die "doppelte Zuweisung" sorgt für einen Neustart des Timers
// cppcheck-suppress redundantAssignment
m_pTimer->Enabled = true;
```

...but it obviously doesn't help, I still see this style warning:

> Variable 'Enabled' is reassigned a value before the old one has been used.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For the command line version inline suppressions must be enabled through the command line switch `--inline-suppr`. For details refer to the [manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf).

For the GUI version you have to activate inline suppressions through the preferences dialog (Menu *Edit*->*Preferences*, tab *General*, *Enable inline suppressions*).

Comment: Good point, but I'm using the GUI version. That I should have added to the question. If I would use the command line version, I'd have created a batch for this ensuring to keep the switch set. The GUI version has to be reconfigured after each update, that was the actual problem: I forgot enable inline suppressions again after a Cppcheck update.

Comment: I've got a notion that the GUI is not so well supported. I always had trouble realising my configurations through the GUI and finally switched to the command line. Although I miss to be able to just click on a warning and directly jump into the editor.

Comment: The warning->editor switching is implemented meanwhile, I use it on a regularly base. BTW: If you'd expand your answer to cover the GUI as well (and maybe also some ref link), I'd accept it.